# speakers can't put it as default win10

Tags: windows-10, audio

I have problem in win10 sound, it's say that the speakers are not connected but they are and the win10 use another pilot or some thing else to run sound

[image]

the second one is worked normally but the first is not, and I can't put it as default

Comment: The first ones are not connected, that's why you can't set them as default and there is no audio coming out of them.

Comment: what are you mean with no connected, because the speakers are really connecte. and how can I know if the sound card work correctly or not.

Comment: to detect if sound card is broken or not I used external sound card and it work, So is the sound card broken or not??

Comment: What plug are you using to connect the speakers? The "Realtek Digital output" is going to be an optical (TOSLINK) or coax (RCA) spdif plug (orange?). The item greyed out in the screenshot is the 1/8 inch TRS (usually green color)

Comment: I use the green for the speakers and the orange/purple for the Mic and one USB